# pragma GCC poison syntax for member function

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, pragma

In GCC (and clang) there is this option to poison a function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma GCC poison puts

int main() {
    puts("a");
}
```

**What would be the syntax to poison a member function of a template class?**

I tried the following options, I didn't even manage to make it work for the non-template class member.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma GCC poison puts

struct A{
  bool operator==(A const& o){return true;}
};

#pragma GCC poison A::operator== //not working

template<class T>
struct B{
  bool operator==(B const& o){return true;}
};

#pragma GCC poison template<class T> B<T>::operator== //not working either


int main() {
    puts("a");
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/rBEgjZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such a syntax. The [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html) says `#pragma GCC poison` is part of the preprocessor itself; indeed, the GCC documentation doesn't even mention it.

That means it only works on things the preprocessor understands, i.e. identifier tokens. Something like `A::operator==` is four separate tokens: `A`, `::`, `operator`, `==`. Of these you could only poison `A` and `operator`; the preprocessor does not understand scopes or classes, let alone templates.

Comment: yeah, in the examples they always poison very low level functions. Maybe one has to put the name of the demangled funcion for the preprocessor to recognize the function. I'll keep using `[[deprecated("msg")]]` until I find a better option.

Comment: @alfC The preprocessor doesn't know about functions, only identifiers. You couldn't even say `{ int puts; }`.

Comment: Ah, ok, so in principle I could poison any valid identifier, types as well?